# Is there a way to support JSON schema references in Paw?

Tags: paw-app

Paw has good tools for documenting simple APIs, but now I need to do something more complicated and I would like to use JSON Schema references.

For example, like the following snippet from the [Swagger 2.0 examples](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore-expanded.json), where the `definitions` are presented later in the document:

```
"post": {
  "description": "Creates a new pet in the store.  Duplicates are allowed",
  "operationId": "addPet",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "pet",
      "in": "body",
      "description": "Pet to add to the store",
      "required": true,
      "schema": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/NewPet"
      }
    }
  ],
...
```

Is there a way to to this in Paw?

Comment: Thanks for asking this. Unfortunately, for now Paw doesn't have this feature yet. It's something we'd love to add in a future version though.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!